# Form validate if any field has value. other wise submit empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to validate a shift form, problem is, if any of the field is fill by user like checkbox or input value, validation on for all over form. other wise form submit empty.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<form>
<input type="text" name="fname"> <br><br>
<input type="text" name="lname"> <br><br>
working days:
<p>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="workingdaysq" value="checkbox" id="workingdaysq_0">
    Sunday</label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="workingdaysq" value="checkbox" id="workingdaysq_1">
    monday</label>
  <br>
</p>

<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use as follows;

```
var valid = false;
$(document).ready(function(){
$('form').data('serialize',$('form').serialize());
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
 if($('form').serialize()!=$('form').data('serialize')){
   alert("User changed");
   valid = false;
   //use user validation code here
 }
 else
   {
     alert("Not changed");
     valid = true;
       }

if(!valid) {
  e.preventDefault();
 }
});
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/w0yb1dmd/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's what i was looking for.

Comment: Thank you once again, you saved my time and code lines :-)

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon your platform, you want to use to validate form.
if you want to use inbuilt form validator by jquery which is quite professional, u can use this link http://www.formvalidator.net/

This example will be suitable for you. if you want to use jquery. http://code.runnable.com/UZJ24Io3XEw2AABU/how-to-validate-forms-in-jquery-for-validation

otherwise you can use simple manual javascript if else conditions also. just find on w3schools for javascipt form validation.